# .htaccess parameters completely ignored when uploading files through PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to limit file size, file type, and number of uploads per request through the .htaccess file, but for some reason my PHP upload script completely bypasses these parameters. Any clues on why this is happening? I've made sure that my webserver works with .htaccess files and the support even recommended me to use these parameters...

What i'm using in the .htaccess file:

```
php_value post_max_size 8M
php_value upload_max_filesize 8M
php_value max_file_uploads 1
```

My upload script:

```
<?php
$secret_key = "REDACTED"; //32-char
$sharexdir = "REDACTED";
$domain_url = "REDACTED"; 
$lengthofstring = 7;
$space= "\x20";
$linkembedu2800 =؜;

function RandomString($length) {
    $keys = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a', 'z'));

    $key = '';
    for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[mt_rand(0, count($keys) - 1)];
    }
    return $key;
}

if(isset($_POST['secret']))
{
    if($_POST['secret'] == $secret_key)
    {
        $filename = RandomString($lengthofstring);
        $target_file = $_FILES["sharex"]["name"];
        $fileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["sharex"]["tmp_name"], $sharexdir.$filename.'.'.$fileType))
        {
            echo $domain_url.$sharexdir.$filename.'.'.$fileType.$space.$linkembedu2800;
        }
            else
        {
            echo 'ERROR: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'ERROR: INVALID SECRET KEY';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'ERROR: NO POST DATA RECIEVED';
}
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'))` to make sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: Sometimes this doesn't work in .htaccess. Why not using php.ini?

Comment: "support even recommended me to use these parameters..." - so you are using mod_php?